# git - show renames in a commit, simple output

Tags: git

I need to see file renames which were done at a commit and be able to parse the output. I have done some research and this is the best I could get:

`git show commit_hash --summary --format=""`

output:

```
 rename src/{old/location => new/place}/lib.ts (100%)
 rename src/{old/location => new/place}/lib.types.ts (100%)
 create mode 100644 src/new/place/index.ts
```

However, I don't want to use it as I think it's difficult to parse - I would have to test different filename edge cases to ensure the paths are always parsed properly.

I'm looking for something like `rename src/old/location/lib.ts to src/new/place/lib.ts`

Using git show without --summary option, prints full file paths (rename from \n rename to) - which would be easy to parse, although it also shows the whole file diff - which is something I don't want. If I understand correctly, the rename from oldpath / rename to newpath is part of the diff itself.

Is there any way to show renames of a commit in a reliable, easy to parse way, without outputting diffs?

Comment: Because `git show` is a porcelain command, not a plumbing one: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Plumbing-and-Porcelain . Try using `git diff-tree --find-renames -r <TREE-ISH>`. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree

Comment: Works great. Thank you.

Comment: I have done some more research, adding the --name-status option to the above command will make the output even leaner. It also appears that ```git diff``` can handle this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using git diff-tree (thanks @fluffy)

`git diff-tree --find-renames -r --name-status --format="" $commit_hash`

Using git diff

`git diff --name-status $commit_hash~ $commit_hash`

Both commands will output something like this:

```
R100 src/old/location/lib.ts src/new/place/lib.ts
R095 src/old/location/lib.types.ts src/new/place/lib.types.ts
A src/new/place/index.ts
```

git diff-tree appears to be the better option, as git diff version will throw a fatal error when trying to retrieve the first commit.